# PDFbox - get line or text font size/format

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm trying to get the font size or format (bold etc.) of a specific text or line from a pdf file, but without any success until now.

Using the PDFTextStripper like below will only get the plain text

> PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
>   String actualText = stripper.getText(actualDoc);

Can you, please, help me with this?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend `PDFTextStripper` and overwrite `PDFTextStripper#processTextPosition`. This method gives you access to a `TextPosition` object, in which font attributes are saved.
Then you need to collect all TextPositions which are located in a specified box (your line) and put them together.

Comment: Alternatively @mihai may overwrite `writeString(String, List<TextPosition>)` --- here the information has already been sorted and filtered.

Comment: @mkl Thanks, I just started looking into PDFbox and your comment helped me too! Overwriting `writeString(String, List<TextPosition>)` should indeed be an easier way to do this.

Comment: That `writeString` overload is a fairly recent addition to the library. Thus, even long-time users of PDFBox may miss it ;).